# HttpServletRequest#getPart doesn't exist?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets

I have a Java WebApp in which I need to upload a file. According to what I've found on the Internet, here's what I've tried:

```
public class FileUploadController extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "C:/uploads";

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    }
```

However, the IDE complained about an undefined symbol `getPart`. So I went ahead and found that you need the Servlet API 3.0 at least to get this method, and my project only had Servlet API 2.5. I changed the required version of the API in the `pom.xml` file from `2.5` to `3.0-alpha-1` (which was proposed by the autocompletion), and clean-built the project.

But I still have this error about `getPart` not existing. Did I miss something?

Comment: Note that I checked in the "Dependencies" folder and that `servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1.jar` is present and that the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` does indeed not define a `getPart` method. I feel very confused right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artifact id was changed to javax.servlet-api somewhere during the development of the 3.0 version of the Servlet API. Version 3.0-alpha-1 is a very early pre-release, which might not yet have the `getPart(String)` method.

To get the current 3.0.x release of the Servlet API, use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yay, happens to do the trick! Thanks a lot! I don't know why autocomplete didn't show this one, I shouldn't rely that much on it. Jokes on me. :)